# How to convert view into bitmap with google map

Tags: android, google-maps, bitmap

I need to get a snapshot of a view in my application. I have a few different things in a RelativeLayout including, google map fragment, 3 progress bars w/ text. The progress bars are showing up fine, however the google map is black when I convert the view into a bitmap.
I do not wish to use the mMap.snapshot() as I will then have to merge the bitmap, and add drawing on top of it since we draw a route on the map. Anyone have a viable solution? Here is the code I am using.

```
private Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
    Date now = new Date();
    RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.screenie_layout);
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);
    Bitmap bitmap1 = null;


    try {
        v.clearFocus();
        v.setPressed(false);

        boolean willNotCache = v.willNotCacheDrawing();
        v.setWillNotCacheDrawing(false);

        // Reset the drawing cache background color to fully transparent
        // for the duration of this operation
        int color = v.getDrawingCacheBackgroundColor();
        v.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(0);

        if (color != 0) {
            v.destroyDrawingCache();
        }
        v.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap cacheBitmap = v.getDrawingCache();
        if (cacheBitmap == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "failed getViewBitmap(" + v + ")", new RuntimeException());
        }

        bitmap1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(cacheBitmap);

        // Restore the view
        v.destroyDrawingCache();
        v.setWillNotCacheDrawing(willNotCache);
        v.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(color);


    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bitmap1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that was pretty easy...

```
private Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
    Date now = new Date();
    RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.screenie_layout);
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);
    Bitmap bitmap1 = null;


    try {
        v.clearFocus();
        v.setPressed(false);

        boolean willNotCache = v.willNotCacheDrawing();
        v.setWillNotCacheDrawing(false);


        v.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap cacheBitmap = v.getDrawingCache();
        if (cacheBitmap == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "failed getViewBitmap(" + v + ")", new RuntimeException());
        }

        bitmap1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(cacheBitmap);

        // Restore the view
        v.destroyDrawingCache();
        v.setWillNotCacheDrawing(willNotCache);


    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return overlay(bitmap1, mMapBitmap);


}
```

//This method will combine the map and another bitmap.

```
private Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 0, 0, null);
    return bmOverlay;
}
```